# Why does Brackets add lines of code when I save?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I started using Brackets two days ago and have had to remove it from my computer. I saved and closed an HTML/JS/PHP project last night (and the night before) and when I open it again in the morning it's broken. Badly.

I noticed it had been adding lines of code for instance, it added the opening tag for a bootstrap md-3 over the footer... without closing it.

I did not put the footer in a bootstrap md-3, nor did I forget to close it. I am the only person (I know of) with access to this document. And there are half a dozen of these per doc.

??

This is really bad as I have lost two days of work now from having to go through and fix them.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the closed editor would cause that. Do you have any extensions installed or any grunt tasks running on that project?

Comment: Yes it is really bizarre. I had 'beautify' and 'themes' on it. No Grunt tasks. Windows 10. It was a Keenthemes template.

Comment: Did the Beautification work for your code? There are issues with a few languages.  
Beautify has an option to "Beautify on Save". Maybe that was turned on?

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't set any options on installation so, if by default, yes. When I set it, I did notice it had moved some indentation, but my files kept working properly afterwards and through several saves. It certainly wasn't adding stray md-3 columns. The errors only became apparent when I opened the project again the following morning day.

I have removed the program now as the cost of this error has already been too great.